# Visual Studio Find and Replace - Exclude Namespaces/Classes/Methods/Variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a solution in Visual Studio with Namespaces/Classes/Methods/Variables named after **`ABC`**. There are coincidentally some presentation aspects (like strings and Views) that contain `ABC`. I am trying to find all of the `ABC` occurances in strings/Views.

Some code might look like this:

```
1  namespace ABC.defghi
2  {
3    public class ABCer
4    {
5       var myVar = "This is my ABC string";
6       public ActionResult onlyABCcan(string ABC)
7       {
8           return View();
9       }
10   }
11 }
```

If I do a search for `ABC` in Visual Studio, it will come up with 5 results.

If I do a search for `ABC`, with match whole word on, it will come up with 3 results.

How can I make it only show one result (line 5)?

Is it possible to make Visual Studio only search through strings in C#, and HTML in Views?

Answer (score 3):

When you do a search, in the `Find Options` panel, you can specify the file types you wish to search in. You can then do a plain search only in HTML files, and then another one on the .cs files, using regular expressions in the latter to search for ABC between quotes. Like this:

```
".*ABC.*"
```

I'm a little rusty with RegEx, actually, so it may be a variation of that.

Comment: Will that work for string literals too? eg: string a = @"mystring with line breaks"

Comment: It should. You could do a quick test.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of Renan (+1 for that) here you have screenshot of the mentioned find-options.

[image]

Comment: If I look in all text in HTML files it will find elements like <div id="my-ABC"></div>. Is there anyway to only search through the content of the HTML elements (similar to above regex but use < instead of " ?). So it wouldn't find <div id="my-ABC"></div> but it would find <div>My content with ABC</div>

Comment: My knowledge in RexEx is limited and at the moment there is no VS in range. So far I can recommend you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx. This should help.